# Regex with multiple start and end characters that must be the same

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like to be able to search for strings inside a special tag in a string in JavaScript. Strings in JavaScript can start with either `"` or `'` character.

Here an example to illustrate what I want to do. My custom tag is called `<my-tag`. My regex is `/('|")*?<my-tag>((.|\n)[^"']*?)<\/my-tag>*?('|")/g`. I use this regex pattern on the following strings:

```
var a = '<my-tag>Hello World</my-tag>'; //is found as expected
var b = "<my-tag>Hello World" + '</my-tag>'; //is NOT found, this is good!
var c = "<my-tag>Hello World</my-tag>"; //is found as expected
var d = '<my-tag>something "special"</my-tag>'; //here the " char causes a problem
var e = "<my-tag>something 'special'</my-tag>"; //here the " char causes a problem
```

It works well with **a** and also **c** where it finds the tag with the containing text. It also does not find the text in **b** which is what I want. But in case **d** and **e** the tag with content is not found due to the occurrence of the `"` and `'` character. What I want is a regex where inside the tag `"` is allowed if the string is start with `'`, and vice versa.

Is it possible to achieve this with one regex, or is the only thing I can do is to work with two separate regex expressions like
`/(")*?<my-tag>((.|\n)[^']*?)<\/my-tag>*?(")/g` and `/(')*?<my-tag>((.|\n)[^"]*?)<\/my-tag>*?(')/g` ?

Comment: As you can see from the complexity of the regexes you already have attempted, regex might not be the best tool here.  Instead, you could try parsing the DOM XML tree and extracting what you want.

Comment: Ok, I can suggest [`/(['"]?)<my-tag>((?:(?!\/?my-tag\b|\1)[\s\S])*)<\/my-tag>\1/`](https://regex101.com/r/fF3iK2/2). I am making the quotes optional since you have `('|")*?` in your regex at the beginning. No regex will look "pretty" here, and you should consider writing/using a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but I think this would work:

```
/("<my-tag>((.|\n)[^"]*?)<\/my-tag>"|'<my-tag>((.|\n)[^']*?)<\/my-tag>')/g
```

Comment: Just FYI: `(.|\n)` = `[^]` in JS regex. Or `[\s\S]`.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use de match from the first match ('|") and reuse it for the second match. Something like the following:

```
/('|")<my-tag>.*?<\/my-tag>\1/g
```

This should make sure to match the same character at the beginning and the end.

But you really shouldn't use regex for parsing HTML.

Comment: You have not even tried your regex anywhere before posting. If I am unsure my solution works, I always test it before posting.

Comment: It does not work. If it would that would be a very good answer.

Comment: Sorry did not test because I was confident it wouls work, fixed it and tested it. Replaced $1 with \1

Comment: @Pit: `/('|")<my-tag>*?<\/my-tag>\1/g` cannot work and you have not tested it properly. Please retry.